# Redirect chain htaccess wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am struggling for some time to solve the redirect chain that WordPress is making and I didn't find yet any solutions.
here is my htaccess:

## BEGIN WordPress

```
enter code here
```

For now makes the redirect chain:
http://www.example.com/dir/product/
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.example.com/dir/product/
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.example.com/product/
200 OK

The idea is to pass those redirect chains and if you could help me out I would really appreciate

The idea is to redirect dir to dir/ dir to product and product to product without a redirect chain

Kind regards

Comment: Please read [ask], and spend a little more time on your question. The title alone is very offputting.

Comment: When you write or edit a question, there's a preview view below the input area. You need to check and see if the resulting post is the one you intended or perhaps some formatting is in order. In the current state of your question, the only way for someone to fully understand what you're asking is by editing your question to see what you wrote and figure from that what you intended...